# Можно ли каким то образом принудительно сменить динамический IP?

Tags: сеть, ip

При подключении по `Ethernet` провайдер выдает динамический IP на определенное время. Иногда он может долго не меняться. Можно ли как то повлиять на выдачу нового динамического IP?

Comment: кто выдает IP? DHCP?

Comment: Может DHCP Release + DHCP renew?

Comment: Как неочень хороший (крайний) вариант, можно через WMI закрыть подключение по сети, и открыть снова. Будет сгенерирован новый IP.

Comment: Решение для Windows на SuperUser: https://superuser.com/q/470585/379403

Comment: Это у провайдера уточняйте. У меня например хоть адрес и по DCHP дается и вроде как динамический, только он к клиенту фактически привязан и всегда выдается один и тот же